# Log HAProxy captured response header in custom format

Tags: haproxy

I have an HAProxy configuration with a custom JSON `log-format`. I want to capture a specific response header and log it.

However, no matter how I try to capture it, I cannot make it appear in the log.

In my log format I use `%[capture.res.hdr(0)]` but it only comes up as `-`. I've also tried `%[res.hdr(0)]` and `%[res.hdr(MyHeader)]` but they were not valid configuration and HAProxy failed to start.

I've tried capturing using:

```
capture response header MyHeader len 50
```

But it doesn't work. I also tried:

```
declare capture response len 50
http-response capture res.hdr(MyHeader) id 0
```

With no success. The `%hs` format variable works - all the captured headers are logged in a delimited string. But I want to log the headers separately as JSON properties.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm currently using HAProxy 1.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the combination of having `capture response header MyHeader len 50` in the `frontend` section and `%[capture.res.hdr(0)]` in the `log-format` actually works. Turns out I had multiple instances of HAProxy running and only reloaded some of them, so the changes only came through for some requests.